# get and set Enum variable inside a class?

Tags: c++, enums

So first I don't know if I declared it right, or initialized it correctly. In the DOCO.h I declared it as an enum then created a variable get and set. I don't know how necessary it is for the variable is only used within this class, but a later version may need to have access to it in a subclass????

So the object DOCO is moving along a 2D array, I want to be able to change the direction of the DOCO by allowing it to have an enum variable. First so as the coder I know what I'm talking about to set it to names like North, South, East and West, but to allow the program to convert it to an integer value.

DOCO.h

{
    private:
    ...
    enum D_direction;

```
public:
...
enum D_direction getD_direction();
void setD_direction(enum D_direction dir);
}
```

DOCO.cpp

```
DOCO::DOCO(void)
{
enum D_direction *direction = 0;
D_energy = 0;
Mycell = NULL;
Nextcell = NULL;
}

enum D_direction DOCO::getD_direction()
{
enum D_direction dir;

    //possible returns------
return *dir;
    /*ERROR: no "*" matches these operands      
      operand types are: *DOCO::D_direction */

    return D_direction *dir
    /*enum DOCO::D_direction, DOCO *Other_proK;
      ERROR: typename is not allowed*/

     return dir;
     /* DOCO::D_direction dir
        ERROR: the return value type does not match the function type*/


}

void DOCO::setD_direction(enum D_direction dir)
{
enum D_direction {No_dir,NW,N,NE,E,SE,S,SW,W};
dir = static_cast<enum D_direction>(rand()%8+1);
    //ERROR: a value type of "D_direction" can't be assigned to an 
    //entity of "DOCO::D_direction"
}
```

So this function is not exactly correct, but this is one way that I wanted to use the enum D_direction *direction variable. I don't think I'm doing the static cast correctly.

```
bool DOCO::checkPosition(W_Cell *mc)
//should the argument be bool *pos?    Don't know if this needs to be used?
{
//use the enum D_direction and pointer to next cell and determine
//current cell is border cell and move is possible
bool pos = false;
//do I need to instantiate the W_Grid?
while (row != -1 && col != -1)
{
if (*direction == NW)
{
   if ((col == 0) || (row == 0)) //top row or 1st col no NW
       pos = false;
   else
       pos = (D_World)grid[row-1][col-1].isDoccupied();
          //can I set all of these true?
}
else if (*direction == N)
{
   if (row == 0) //top row no N nextcell
       pos = false;
   else
       pos = (D_World)grid[row-1][col+1].isDoccupied();
}
else if (*direction == NE)
{
   if ((row == 0) || (col = width - 1) 
          //top row or last col no NE nextcell
       pos = false;
   else
       pos = D_World::grid[row-1][col+1].getDoccupied();
}
else if (*direction == E)
{
   if (col = width - 1) //last col no E nextcell
       pos = false;
   else
       pos = (D_World)grid[row][col+1].isDoccupied();
}
else if (*direction == SE)
{
   if ((row == (height -1))||col == (width - 1))) 
       //last row or col no SE nextcell
       pos = false;
   else
       pos = (D_World)grid[row+1][col+1].isDoccupied();
//or can I say this is setNextcell(dOC);
}
else if (*direction == S)
{
   if ((row == (height -1)) //last row no S nextcell
       pos = false;
   else
       pos = (D_World)grid[row+1][col].isDoccupied();
//or can I say this is setNextcell(dOC);
}
else if (*direction == SW)
{
   if ((row == (height -1) || (col == 0)) 
         //last row or 1st col no SW nextcell
       pos = false;
   else
       pos = (D_World)grid[row+1][col].isDoccupied();
//or can I say this is setNextcell(dOC);
}
else if (*direction == W)
{
   if (col = 0) //1st col no W nextcell
       pos = false;
   else
       pos = (D_World)grid[row][col-1].getDoccupied();
}
else
   pos = false;
}
return pos;
}
```

This function shows how I want to use this variable. I don't have any errors calling the variable, but I don't know if this is using it correctly.
    void DOCO::setNextcell(W_Cell *nc)
    {
    W_Cell *Nextcell = new W_Cell;
    D_World *grid = new D_World;

```
if (Nextcell= grid-> getCell(row, col))
{
    if (Nextcell -> getP_occupied())
           /*how to get pointer to where cell is on grid?*/
    this -> checkPosition(nc);
          /*so this will point to grid->getCell(row,col)?*/

    if (Nextcell->getD_occupied())
        this -> getD_direction;
}
Nextcell = nc;
}
```

So here are the errors that I think that I'm getting with this. In the DOCO.h I'm not getting any errors. But in the DOCO.cpp there are many errors. I don't know really what to ask, but here is what I think is relevant to my question. I want to use the enum variable to change the direction of the DOCO around a block in a grid. I am going to use upperleft(NW), Upper(N), upperright(NE), right(E), lowerright(SE), lower(S), lowerleft(SW), and right(W) as my directions with row and col to set the directions. Hopefully this is not an easy stupid answer, but since I don't know please tell :)

Comment: Move your enum definition outside the function body

Answer (score 0):

When reading the provided source code, I can see some wavering between variable and pointer (`enum D_direction *direction` and `should the argument be bool *pos?`).

> To be clear, all simple variable types as `int`, `float`, ... and
>   `enum` could be entered to or returned from a function without needed
>   a pointer.

To use an enum in a class, it is really simple:

**Step1** - declaration of the `enum` with the `class`:

> The `enum` is a set of symbolic parameter declared before to be used

```
enum D_direction { D_None,
        D_NW, D_N, D_NE, D_E,
        D_SE, D_S, D_SW, D_W
    };
```

> In the `class`, the `enum` is used as `int` with a private data and
>   get/set public functions.

```
class DOCO {
private:
    enum D_direction e_dir;
public:
    DOCO();
    enum D_direction getD_direction();
    void setD_direction(enum D_direction dir);
};
```

**Step2** - Use the `enum` as natural variable type.

```
DOCO::DOCO()
{
    e_dir = D_None;
}

enum D_direction DOCO::getD_direction()
{
    return (e_dir);
}

void DOCO::setD_direction(enum D_direction dir)
{
    e_dir = dir;
}
```

**Step3** - then use the `enum` with your `class`:

```
DOCO vDoco;
enum D_direction e_mydir;

e_mydir = static_cast<enum D_direction>(rand()%(D_W-D_NW)+D_NW); //8+1);
vDoco.setD_direction(e_mydir);
```

Comment: Thanks! My professor suggested making it a global variable which that worked, but I still have problem with the get function...although as a global it probably isn't necessary...eh...what can I say I'm learning.                                                                                                      I didn't think about using the enum variables to set the parameters of rand()%. So again thanks, I'll try this.

Comment: In fact, the **Step3** was described to be inserted inside your `main()` function or any others.

Comment: So read your comment again, I see that you were saying the same as my professor...oops. :D

Comment: So if I wanted to use it in another function within the DOCO class, Step 3 should be used? But doesn't that mean the get and set are not really necessary? Let's just say I'm a little confused :)

Comment: Yay! No swigglies :)         So I tried the random generator in the set function, and it seems to work. I guess we'll see if it runs when I try to compile.

Comment: In OOP, because data should not be declared as `public`, functions as `get/set` are the public access. Both `get/set` functions could be more complex than my basic example.